# read response from ajax request in blocks before its complete

Tags: javascript, ajax

My browser makes an ajax/json request to the server, which then calls out of several services to get data (taking various lengths of time) and then displays this data in the browser.

I could, wait for the server to complete and return all the data in one big go.

Ideally I would like it to return the data (json) whenever each of the individual calls completes. This way I can display them in the UI and if one of the service calls takes a long time, then the user can still look at the data, without looking at a blank screen.

I think its possible to get an ASP.NET web page or handler to send data back to the requesting client without buffering it.

But clientside, how can I process ajax response before its completed? Is this even possible?

I'm wondering if multipart MIME data type may be useful as well...?

Comment: How about you break them up into separate requests?

Comment: I initially have it working like that but was concerned about browser and server impact. Having one call instead of 5 say 5 ajax waiting on the browser. And also having say 5 requests per user on the server rather than one.  I think the browsers have a limit on the max number of simultaneous ajax requests, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It is not a limit on Ajax requests, it is a limit on the number of http connections. Yes there is a limit, but can't you break it up so the process that takes long is in its own request? You can also change it to a polling type of interface. Make a request and have it return what you have at that time. There is also WebSockets on the newer browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know which would take longer and potentially one may even be unavailable and it would have to wait for a timeout. I expect they would normally return within a few seconds, but some may return within half a second and other 5secs. I think polling would just create even more traffic on the server. Sadly, we're not up to the newer browsers yet, but good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate controller/function (depending on what backend you're using), and then make separate requests in your javascript. Since Javascript is asynchronous, results will display on your page as each function completes.

.NET pseudocode

```
public string Foo() {
    string returnedJson = getFoo();
    return returnedJson;
}
//Same thing for Bar and Bah
```

Then, in your Javascript (assuming you're using jQuery)

```
function onFooComplete() {
    //In this function, display the data you get back from the server
}

$.get('/foo', function(res) {
    onFooComplete(res);
});
```

For a more robust implantation, look into using a publish/subscribe methodology in your javascript. https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-tiny-pubsub is a very small but useful pub/sub implementation for jquery.

Comment: yes, this is pretty much what I have at the moment, but using the jquery .done and .fail methods to wrap several calls. I was hoping to combine them into a single request.